# How can I show my enum in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is my custom textBox:

```
public class TextBoxInputNumbers : TextBox
{
    Regex regex;
    public enum DatatypesInput
    {
        Integer, Decimals
    }

    public TextBoxInputNumbers()
    {
        DatatypeInput = DatatypesInput.Integer;
    }

    public DatatypesInput DatatypeInput
    {
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case DatatypesInput.Integer:
                    regex = new Regex("[^0-9.-]+");
                    break;
                case DatatypesInput.Decimals:
                    regex = new Regex("[^0-9-]+");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
    }
}
```

And I'd like to show the property DatatypeInput in XAML, but they cannot recognize any element of my enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the enun name to a string using the Enum.GetName() method:

```
    get
    {
        return Enum.GetName(typeof(DatatypesInput), value);
    }
```

and then bind to that value in your XAML.

Is that what you are looking for? Use Enum.GetNames() is you need the list of all valid names.